# operation on a pandas Interval

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

```
r = [[0,2],[2,4],[4,6],[6,8]]
i = [pd.Interval(x[0],x[1]) for x in r]
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":["a","b","a","b"],"i":i})
```

I'm trying to perform an operation on the column with interval data

```
df["sum"] = df.apply(lambda x: sum(x.i),axis=1)
```

but I get an error

```
TypeError: ("'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object is not iterable", u'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: What are you expecting as output? How do you define the sum of an `Interval`?

Comment: If you want the sum of the start and end values for each interval, you can use `lambda x: x.i.left + x.i.right`

Comment: @Blorgbeard, thanks! I just wanted to know how I can access the contents of the interval to do some calculations on its values. The `.left` `.right` did the trick

Comment: Great! I found those by looking [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Interval.html) btw.